# How to avoid broken thematic sections (eg. div) in HTML?

Tags: css, html, pagination

I am trying to transfer a text from a printed book into HTML5, but meanwhile I am trying to keep its thematic and page/paragraph/lines layout structure exactly as it is. For example, every page of the printed book is divided as a `<div>` section eg. `<div class=page id=55>` so that it emulates/represents exactly the page unit of the printed book, and also facilitate referencing. I don't care much how the text will be rendered on the browser, this is something that I can think about later. I just want the HTML and the browser to "know" the original pagination and layout of the printed book.

The problem is that in the printed book, some paragraphs or even boxes, tables etc span over to the next page. If I translate it to HTML, I do it like this:

```
<div class=page id=1>
<p>Once upon a time...</p>
...
<p>...and so the bold knight
</div>
<div class=page id=2>
slew the evil dragon.</p>
<p>Text...</p>
...
```

This is illegal in HTML, as we have a `<p>` tag being interrupted by a `</div>` tag, and then a new div element beginning with a plain text, which is closed by a `</p>` tag.

HTML would expect me to close the first part of the broken paragraph with a `</p>`, and continue with a new `<p>` tag after the div, but I am not doing this because it doesn't correspond to the pagnation of the original book, and would result in half-paragraphs being understood are 2 proper paragraphs.

So, how to use legal HTML while maintaining the theoretical page/paragraph/broken paragraph/page break structure and information, or at least making the brower "know" the original pagination? Is there a more appropriate tag or method to emulate the page break while keeping the page number id?

Perhaps something like

```
<p>...and so the brave knight<some tag(s) that show page 2 begins here>killed the dragon</p>
```

Comment: There's not much you can do here with HTML & CSS. The browser will close *unclosed* `p` tags for you but it won't open new ones where there's no opening `p` tag. You have a long journey ahead with JS and, I suspect *regex*.

Comment: Wrapping in a "page" div is the wrong approach. As you suggest at the bottom, you want some sort marker that you can put in the middle of a paragraph to indicate a page break. An empty span would work, I might be tempted to exploit microdata and use a `<meta>` element with an itemprop attribute there. But I don't think there's anything specific in HTML for that purpose.

Comment: @Alohci this seems to be on the right track, would you write me a proper answer with some example(s) using these tags?

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of encapsulating each page within a div you include a tag at the start of each page designating the page number. An [aside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside) tag seems appropriate for this.

```
<aside class="page-number" data-page="1">Page 1</aside>
<p>Once upon a time...</p>
<p>...and so the bold knight</p>
<aside class="page-number" data-page="2">Page 2</aside>
<p class="continued">slew the evil dragon.</p>
<p>Text...</p>
```

If you need to continue a paragraph then you'll have to break into multiple elements, but perhaps you can specify when a paragraph is a continuation of a previous one. For instance using the `continued` class as shown above.

If you *really* don't want to break the `p` tag then you could put a `span` within it that is only used for semantic reasons. Something like this;

```
<p>...and so the bold knight 
<span class="page-marker" aria-hidden="true" data-page="1"></span>
slew the evil dragon.</p>
```

But this kind of makes less semantic sense than the previous solution.

Comment: This seems to be in the right track! Would it be illegal to put the `<aside>` tag in the middle of a paragraph, i.e. without breaking it into two?

Comment: @Voprosnik Yeah you can't put an `aside` within the `p` tag, only prose is allowed. If you really didn't want to break the `p` then I guess you could put a blank span in the middle that isn't shown. I'll update my answer

Comment: One more question. Is `aria-hidden="true"` supposed to be included in every span tag? Since there is already a `class="page-marker"`, can't I include it in the css section?

Comment: @Voprosnik `aria-hidden` just tells screen readers not to read that part :)

Comment: I got it, but I guess I should put it in the css section instead of every page. And what about `data-page=`? Is it a valid CSS attribute? I haven't found anything about it online.

Comment: @Voprosnik No, you can specify any custom attributes using `data-*`. That is a custom attribute I just invented for your page numbers to help it make semantic sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: inline;` to either the CSS style of the class `page` or the `style` attribute of each page `div`.